# Why is @font-face not working?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, custom-font

I am trying to use `@font-face` to use a custom font on a site I'm designing. I can't figure out why it's not working this time. I've used it before with no problem.

Here is my code(not from the actual site, but a simplified version I used to test the issue):

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
<p>Loremm ipsum</p>
</body>
</html>
```

css(I left the reset in)

```
/*--------------------------*/
/*----------RESET-----------*/
/*--------------------------*/

/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    font-family:myfont;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/*-------------------------*/
/*-----------MAIN----------*/
/*-------------------------*/

@font-face {
    font-family:myfont;
    src:url('./fonts/myfont.ttf'),
        url('./fonts/myfont.eot');
}
```

my index.html is in `html/`

my font files are in `html/fonts/`

my css is in `html/css/`

Can anyone see the problem?

I have tested this in chrome and firefox and it is on my computer for editing.

Comment: `../fonts/myfont.ttf` etc. should work. On a server just `/` should suffice as a absolute path.

Comment: @Allendar Wouldn't '../fonts/myfont.ttf' look for a folder called fonts inside the folder above html/ ?

Comment: No; the folder traverses up first (from /html/css/ to /html/) and then go down again inside /fonts/. CSS interprets from it's included file's path, not the HTML file's relative location. The Developer Tool/Firebug should also show where it would've tried to include it from, and if it worked/failed.

Comment: Does the `font:inherit;` declaration have anything to do with it? Perhaps removing it would solve the problem. I can't tell though because I can't see a demo.

Comment: @Allendar Alright, that was my issue. In the past I have used a base tag in the head tags which I guess alters how this works. Without the base tags I needed to use ../fonts/myfont.ttf

Wish you had posted this as an answer, I would give you the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make a guess that your src is relative to your CSS file location and your './' is not getting you to the right directory. Give the src an absolute address to your font and make sure it works that way.

I also don't see where you apply the font-family to any of your elements.

Comment: The font-family is set in the RESET

Answer (score 0):

I have always had issues with @font. Hopefully this will assist you.

style.css (get the ota, woff, ttf and svg font type). Make sure that you can find the font by instructions given to the HTML. E.g. if its located in html/fonts/ then the urls should be fonts/blah.eot.

```
 @font-face {
     font-family:'Carrosserie-Medium';
     src: url('../webfonts/FAFC3_0.eot');
     src: url('../webfonts/FAFC3_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../webfonts/FAFC3_0.woff') format('woff'), url('../webfonts/FAFC3_0.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../webfonts/FAFC3_0.svg#wf') format('svg');
 }
 @font-face {
     font-family:'Carrosserie-Thin';
     src: url('../webfonts/FAFC3_1.eot');
     src: url('../webfonts/FAFC3_1.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../webfonts/FAFC3_1.woff') format('woff'), url('../webfonts/FAFC3_1.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../webfonts/FAFC3_1.svg#wf') format('svg');
 }
.Carrosserie-Medium {
    font-family: Carrosserie-Medium;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
.Carrosserie-Thin {
    font-family: Carrosserie-Thin;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Implementing it

```
h2#tagline {font-size:30px;font-family:'Carrosserie-Thin', sans-serif; }
```

HTML

```
<h2 id="tagline">Try this.</h2>
```