# Why is @font-face not working in this code snippet?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

When I try to use `font-face` it just does nothing, it doesn't change the font. Why is it not working?
Here is my HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="schriftarten.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <span id="span1">Hallo Welt</span>
    </body>

</html>
```

Here is my CSS Code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Test";
  src: url("Anton-Regular.ttf") format("ttf");
  font-style:normal;
}

#span1{
  background-color:orange;
  font-size:30px;
  font-family:Test;
}
```

What am i doing wrong? I'm using Chrome Version 84.0.4147.135 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is @font-face not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862726/why-is-font-face-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use all types of font for matching all browsers standards here is an example to give you the idea about your css code:

```
@font-face{
font-family:YOUR_FONT_NAME;
src:url('YOUR_FONT_NAME.eot');
src:url('YOUR_FONT_NAME.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('YOUR_FONT_NAME.woff') format('woff'),url('YOUR_FONT_NAME.ttf') format('truetype'),url('YOUR_FONT_NAME.svg#weberdsBold') format('svg');
```

}

Comment: i just downloaded the woff and eot version of the font and tried it. nothing happens again.

Comment: I generally put a file called font.css in the home directory and put all the fonts there as well. Then I put the `@font-face` in font.css and `@import` to that font.css in my stylesheet. Seems to work every time...

Comment: @AlwinSchneider can you please upload your files online or create a JSFiddle so I can take a look and find out what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution.
The error was the format("ttf")
when i removed it, it was fine